# Why Allure report is showing empty contents in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, webdriver-io, allure

After installing Allure report plugin in Jenkins, getting this -
ALLURE REPORT UNKNOWN
unknown - unknown (Unknown)
0
test cases
NaN%

It's show no result, after build execution is done. My project structure just like this -

Root folder >> Marcombox (webdriverIO project) like the image - [!Repository folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/la150.png)

I am getting the Allure report option in each build, after build is successfully done. Here is my Post-build Actions looks like -

```
Paths to Allure results directories relative from workspace.
Marcombox/allure-results
Report path:
Marcombox/allure-report
```

[Path of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyQUq.png) and
[Report Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGIpy.png)
Below is the cmd, I am using -

```
cd Marcombox && npm install && npm run npx wdio lamda.wdio.conf.js
npm install -g allure-commandline --save-dev
npm run allure generate reports --clean && allure open
```

here is the workplace of Jenkins - [workplace of Jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8UZp.png)
In console output, I found this -

```
C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\tools\ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation\ALLURE_HOME\bin\allure.bat generate 
"C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Automation Test\Marcombox\allure-results" -c -o 
"C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Automation Test\Marcombox\allure-report"
Report successfully generated to C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Automation Test\Marcombox\allure-report
Allure report was successfully generated.
Creating artifact for the build.
Artifact was added to the build.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

there is data inside Marcombox/allure-results - like the pic -
[data in folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTADj.png)

```
Automation Test
/
Marcombox
/
allure-results
/

data
export
history
plugins
widgets
app.js  Sep 26, 2023, 4:04:08 PM    764.87 KB
executor.json   Sep 26, 2023, 4:05:27 PM    275 B
favicon.ico Sep 26, 2023, 4:04:08 PM    15.04 KB
index.html  Sep 26, 2023, 4:04:08 PM    1.04 KB
styles.css  Sep 26, 2023, 4:04:08 PM    1.45 MB
testrun.json    Sep 26, 2023, 4:05:27 PM    73 B
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Plugin Installation:
Ensure that the Allure Jenkins plugin is installed and configured correctly. Go to "Manage Jenkins" > "Manage Plugins" and search for "Allure." Make sure it's installed and up to date.

Comment: It is installed otherwise Allure Report options will not appear in each build

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not need to run the allure install and allure generate command on Jenkins
2. Make sure you specify the correct path of the `allure-results` as present in the allure reporter config in your `wdio.config.js` file
3. Make sure the specified path in the Jenkins Job configuration under the Allure plugin exists. Please note that it is relative to the **workspace** on Jenkins.

Comment: I have updated my questions. Can you specify which path, I need to change. I already mentions the current paths.

Comment: Can you show us your project folder structure, specifically where the `allure-results` folder is and also the configuration of the Allure Plugin in your Jenkins job post build actions?

Comment: please have a look, I added project folder structure and allure-results folder. Please suggest me what should I do? Thanks in advance

Comment: I added project folder structure, you can see the picture by clicking that link, kindly suggest me where I should change?

Comment: Do not run these commands as you are using the allure jenkins plugin

```
npm install -g allure-commandline --save-dev
npm run allure generate reports --clean && allure open
```

Comment: remove that cmd and got the same result

Comment: is it possible that, this is write permission in jenkins? because the report shows properly in local

Comment: do you see any files in the `Marcombox/allure-results` folder with data inside them?

Comment: yes I do there is data and I again update the questions with pic for details

Comment: I answered what you asked so please tell me the way to fix this

Comment: Go to "Manage Jenkins" > "Global Tool Configuration" > "Allure Commandline". Here select latest version, save and retry build